# How does the oauth authorization header work in realation to a 'simple' api url?

Tags: api, oauth, sas

I am new to pulling data via APIs, so I hope this question is reasonable. In general, I have experience retrieving the data via json once passed through a url: eg. http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json. From there I can obtain the data I need, simple enough.

Where I am struggling is understanding how to implement this with an Oauth authentication. I have four keys, the app key, secret, access token, and access token secret.

I've read that this needs to be implemented in the following manner:

via the authorization header 
 Authorization:

```
            OAuth realm="http://sp.example.com/",
            oauth_consumer_key="xxxxx",
            oauth_token="xxxxx",
            oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_signature="xxxxx",
            oauth_timestamp="137131200",
            oauth_nonce="xxxxx",
            oauth_version="1.0"
```

which comes from: https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process

Is there a 'url' type way to obtain the data I need in json format? I certainly have all required information, I just am not sure how to implement it.

(I'm using SAS)

Comment: Try using `Proc HTTP` to query a url with custom headers (`HEADERIN=` option) and parameter data (`IN=` option).  Newer versions of SAS include a JSON library engine, you may need to develop a JSONMAP for the delivered results depending on the 'nest-iness' of the json.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on generation of the actual authorization header with the keys?